# Sort posts by their date in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type `Archiv Kursunterlagen` with some custom fields such as `post_date`. I want the posts of that post type to show in descending order by the custom field. I tried looking into other answers and modified the query. But it didn't work.

```
    function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // only modify queries for 'archive' post type
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'archiv_kursunterlage' ) {
        
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');    
        $query->set('meta_key', 'post_date');
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        
    }

    return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

I have put this in a snippet and set it to run everywhere. Am I doing it right? or is there any problem with the query itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the line in your code:

$query->set('order', 'DESC');

Please visit the link for more details:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/

or

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

Comment: I did..but doesn't work..you can visit the page here https://vhs.dinnova.ch/kursunterlagen/ ..you'll see all the posts are not in order with the date below the description.